# Create Spin Progress bar in Qt

Tags: qt, qml

Create Spin Progress bar in Qt, I want to show progress bar like the one which appears while loading. Please Find Image [image]

My code goes like this

```
    QProgressBar *pgbar = new QProgressBar();
    pgbar->resize(500,25);
    pgbar->setOrientation(Qt::Horizontal);
    pgbar->setRange(0,99);
    pgbar->setValue(10);
    pgbar->show();
    installOnDevice(destinationSavePath);
    pgbar->hide();
```

here `installOnDevice(destinationSavePath);` takes time to process. Currently I am showing `Processbar`, I dont want to show `processbar`. Can't I replace with some progress which shows `loading image` (Rotating) or something similar to that

Comment: I don't get your question. Do you want to know how to implement that or are you asking us to find an image you can use?

Comment: You can use gif image instead of QProgressbar..... The sample image can be easily find on google in gif image format and use it for ur purpose.....

Comment: @ JustMaximumPower, Thanks for Comment . Now  I am using QProgressbar do. I want to display some Loading Progress bar instead of showing % process.

Answer (score 6):

Have a look at the [Twitter Mobile](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/demos-declarative-twitter.html) example application. In the file [demos/declarative/twitter/qml/twitter/TwitterCore/Loading.qml](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/demos-declarative-twitter-qml-twitter-twittercore-loading-qml.html) there is an implementation in QML of the exact thing you want to achieve:

```
import QtQuick 1.0

Image {
    id: loading
    source: "images/loading.png"
    NumberAnimation on rotation {
         from: 0
         to: 360
         running: loading.visible == true
         loops: Animation.Infinite
         duration: 900
     }
}
```

---

### Update 1 (reflecting the newly posted code):

Employing QML just for a spinning load indicator in your otherwise Qt Widgets based application seems overkill to me. I would use a [`QMovie`](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qmovie.html) in conjunction with a [`QLabel`](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qlabel.html) to display an animated GIF image containing the spinner:

```
QMovie* spinnerMovie = new QMovie(":/spinner.gif");
QLabel *spinnerLabel = new QLabel(this);
spinnerLabel->setMovie(spinnerMovie);
spinnerMovie->start();
```

You should also have a look at the documentation for the [Qt Resource System](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/resources.html) to learn how to bundle images with your application and how to load them.

Comment: I am new to Qt, the code you showed is QML how can I use it in my Qt Code. Plz suggest me

Comment: Then please update your question to include the portion of your code where you want the progress indicator integrated. Vague questions result in equally vague answers. Also you've tagged your question with QML, you know?

Comment: @ sebasgo , I have edited my quest can you please check it once

Comment: Is there a way to let the `QMovie` overlap the widgets on the screen? i.e make it float over them

Answer (score 2):

In order to change the cursor wou have to use the [setCursor](http://doc.qt.digia.com/qt/qwidget.html#cursor-prop) function or the [setOverrideCursor](http://doc.qt.digia.com/qt/qapplication.html#setOverrideCursor) in order to apply it to the application. You can construct any cursor you want using a [QPixmap](http://doc.qt.digia.com/qt/qcursor.html#QCursor-4) as constructor argument.

In order to achieve an animation effect you will need a [QTimer](http://doc.qt.digia.com/qt/qtimer.html). At every timer event you have to change the cursor's pixmap in order give the feel of animation.

Answer (score 1):

Try Qml Busy Indicator, implemented in pure C++:
    http://qt-project.org/wiki/Busy-Indicator-for-QML