# Circular progress indicator widget in PyQt5

Tags: qt, pyqt, progress-bar, pyqt5

I wonder what would be the best way to implement a **circular** progress indicator **widget** similar to the one shown below in PyQt5?

[image]

Comment: As of Qt 5.4 there's no built-in busy spinner. See also this Stack Overflow question and answers: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13393174/create-spin-progress-bar-in-qt

Comment: The question was only answered for C++ previously and quite poorly in my opinion. It would be good to see a self contained solution for PyQt.